# Android firebase broadcast causes app crash

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have this code,

```
     try {
        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);

            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        } else {
            // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

it was working perfectly, but suddenly the app crashes when it receives a notification on this line:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);
```

the catch exception is never entered !
I can see in the logcat:

```
com.package.myapp E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
```

Comment: Take a look at `logcat`, do a filter by `Error` to see Errors only. If you are using Android Studio, then you can find logcat in the android monitor tab towards the bottom when running your application, then click logcat tab.

Comment: thanks, logcat is only showing 
07-17 23:17:06.843 7462-9368/com.myapp,holE/MyFirebaseMessagingService: From: 215121005
07-17 23:17:06.844 7462-9368/com.plexis.holford E/MyFirebaseMessagingService: Notification Body: ertfdsd

Comment: Clear it, stop your application. Rerun it and keep an eye on it after it crashes. If you see the errors there then include them in your question.

Comment: thank you all, this is the error now :
com.package.myapp E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)

Comment: That error seems unrelated, note that your exception is possibly being caught but the `Toast` may not be working. So instead of toast, add a  `Log.e("MYAPP", ex.getMessage());`. You can then find this message in the `logcat` window, type in the filter search bar `MYAPP`.

Comment: @Dayan I tried, but also not logged, i have this code statments to play custom sound,   
final Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                   + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");